# Access private object using java reflection api

Tags: java, reflection

Can I access and get the value of object using java reflection

ther is method to get --getLong,getInt ,but I couldn't find getObject()

Comment: Could you explain what you're trying to do? Maybe there is a better way to do what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for simply [`Field.get(Object obj)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29)?

Comment: BTW: You can use get() on all fields types including primitives.

Comment: And in order to access private fields you should call `field.setAccessible(true);`

Comment: @Noam: Yup. I'm assuming the OP is happy with getting at the field etc, and it's just the `get` method they couldn't find.

Answer (score 0):

`Class  aClass = MyObject.class

   Field field = aClass.getField("someField");`

The example above will return the Field instance corresponding to the field someField
   as declared in the MyObject below:

`public class MyObject{

     public String someField = null;

   }`

If no field exists with the name given as parameter to the getField() method, a
   NoSuchFieldException is thrown.